# Autohotkey - Send keystroke when mouse touch edge of screen twice?

Tags: autohotkey

I need a script that can do something similar that this script is doing:

`~Escape::
  If (A_ThisHotkey=A_PriorHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<250)
    Send !{F4}
return`

This script sends Alt+F4 when Esc key is pressed twice fast.

I need a script that can sends keystroke when the mouse touch the right edge of the screen two times in less then a second. If the mouse touch the edge only once nothing should happen.

Anyone know if this can be implemented with autohotkey?

Comment: Yes, it can be implemented in AHK. You could use a loop/timer that runs very frequently and compares the current cursor position with the respective window edge. However, this algorithm would have nothing to do with code you posted, since you can't represent a "mouse-over event" with a hotkey. More importantly, I suspect the nature of this mouse gesture to be very error prone. What should happen if the user crosses the right border, and then returns back to the window (e.g. when closing the right-hand window)? And generally, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a script that should answer your question. Each 10 milliseconds, we get the position of the mouse. If it was on the edge and has now moved off of it, we count that as a "tap" and start a 1 second timer (1000 milliseconds, the actual argument in the code is negative since we want it to run only once). Each tap also increments `taps` by one, so we can keep track of how many taps there are. At the end of the 1 second timer, we see if the user has tapped the edge of the screen twice. If so, send the Alt-F4 keystroke!

```
;; by default ahk gets mouse coordinates relative to the active
;; window, this sets it to use absolute coordinates
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

;; how often to get the mouse position in milliseconds
UPDATE_INTERVAL := 10
RIGHT_EDGE      := A_ScreenWidth - 1

;; make the script run forever
#Persistent
SetTimer, WatchCursor, %UPDATE_INTERVAL%
return

WatchCursor:
    MouseGetPos, xpos
    ;; a tap is defined by touching and leaving the edge,
    ;; we don't want to count holding the mouse at the edge
    ;; as a tap
    if (prev = RIGHT_EDGE && xpos != RIGHT_EDGE) {
        taps += 1
        ; negative time means run once
        SetTimer, EdgeTimer, -1000
    }
    prev := xpos
return

EdgeTimer:
    ;; more than 2 taps are ignored
    if (taps = 2) {
        Send !{F4}
    }
    taps := 0
return
```

Comment: Thanks, working great. How can i change the script to work in the same way when the mouse touches the top, bottom and left edge of the screen? Which parts of the script should be modified?

Comment: Funny you should reply now! I just got done rewriting it and it should be a lot clearer now and easier to modify. The resolution of the screen is held by two AutoHotkey variables, `A_ScreenWidth` and `A_ScreenHeight`. By comparing the mouse position to these two, we can tell if we're one the edge of the screen or not. In this script we only needed the X coordinates of the mouse, but if you also want the Y coordinates the line that gets the mouse position should be changed to `MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos`. Remember, as I mentioned in the comment, a tap means hitting the edge _and_ leaving it.

Comment: You will also have to store the previous `ypos` in a variable as well. After that it's simply a matter of changing the large `if` statement in `WatchCursor` to detect the correct edge.